# RecyclerView SimpleItemDivider not add divider in between

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, divider

I am trying to add some space between every list item in the recycler view but it's not working accordingly for some reasons. I've been following a guide to implement this solution but cannot seem to find the answer. It's adding the space but the space is placed over the next list item.

This is what my recyclerview currently looks like:-
[My RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvKEh.png)

Here are my classes:-
divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <size
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp" />

    <solid 
        android:color="@color/white"/>

</shape>
```

SimpleDividerItemDecoration class

```
public class SimpleDividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private Drawable mDivider;

    public SimpleDividerItemDecoration(Context context) {
        mDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.divider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

onCreate method in my Fragment class where I get the objects

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popular_picks, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.popular_pick_recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getContext()));

        getPopularPost();

        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to add space consider adding it to item layout(.xml file for your list item). This can be some padding for each item in `RecyclerView`.

If you need to add just regular divider consider using default `DividerItemDecoration`. It available from appcompat library `25.0.0`.

You can add it in this way:

```
mDividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
         mLayoutManager.getOrientation());
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(mDividerItemDecoration);
```

Answer (score 0):

add following line code, hope it will resolve your issue

recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));

and here the class GridSpacingItemDecoration

/**
     * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
     */

```
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge) {
            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                outRect.top = spacing;
            }
            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
        } else {
            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
            if (position >= spanCount) {
                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Converting dp to pixel
 */
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}
```

Comment: I've made changes to the class but i don't think grid spacing would work exactly like i want on the recyclerview because the list item are moved over to the left and right. Is there a way to forget about left and right spacing and only consider top and bottom?

Answer (score -1):

Why not just add custom view on the bottom of the recyclerview item with the background you've created?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22513450)

Comment: @dwirony this provides an answer to the question.

Comment: @double-beep Not in my opinion, and I did not flag or down-vote the answer. Any answer that is a question to OP should be posted as a comment.